# Subquery - Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'declare'

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, declare

Having an issue debugging this, hoping someone can help me clear this up. This is part of a much longer query, but the subquery "B" is the only part that is causing a problem, not sure why... I'm obviously missing something. I'm using sql-server.

The sub query runs fine on its own, just not with the rest of the query.

```
DECLARE @dstrt AS DATETIME
SET @dstrt = '2020-09-01 00:00:00'

DECLARE @dend AS DATETIME
SET @dend = '2020-09-30 23:59:59'


    DECLARE @UnpaidChgsTot table 
    (
    SiteID INT,
    Period nvarchar(30),
    dcDlqntTot money,
    iDelUnits int,
    dcPctUnits money,
    dcPctGrossPot money,
    dcPctActOcc money,
    iDatePeriod int
    )

    DECLARE @sLanguageTermColName nvarchar(20)
    SET @sLanguageTermColName = 'English'

    -- DECLARE some period counters
    DECLARE @StartDayNumber int
    DECLARE @EndDayNumber int
    SET @StartDayNumber = 0
    SET @EndDayNumber = -1

    --Hold the original date value
    DECLARE @dEndORig datetime
    SET @dEndORig = @dEnd

    DECLARE @dcGrossPotDenom money
    DECLARE @dcActOccDenom money
    DECLARE @iTotUnitsDenom int

    SET @dcGrossPotDenom =  1 
    SET @dcActOccDenom = 1
    SET @iTotUnitsDenom = 1
    --Define a holding table for charge balances by ChargeID
    DECLARE @BalT table
    (
        SiteID int,
        ChargeID int,
        LedgerID int,
        ChargeDescID int,
        sChgCategory nvarchar(20),
        sDefAcctCode nvarchar(20),
        dChgStrt datetime,
        dcBalAmt money,
        dcBalTax1 money,
        dcBalTax2 money
    )

    /*
     *  Updated.  Delete was taking too long to run, added to WHERE to get rid
     *  Date: 10192009
     *  Josh
     */
     --Fill the @BalT with charge balances for charges <=dEND
    INSERT INTO @BalT
    SELECT
        B.SiteID,
        B.ChargeID,
        B.LedgerID,
        B.ChargeDescID,
        CD.sChgCategory,
        CA.sDefAcctCode,
        B.dChgStrt,
        dcAmt,
        dcTax1,
        dcTax2
    FROM           -- PROBLEM STARTS HERE
    (
      DECLARE @ChargesT2 table
      (
        SiteID int,
        ChargeID int,
        ChargeDescID int,
        sChgCategory nvarchar(50),
        sDefAcctCode nvarchar(5),
        dChgStrt datetime,
        LedgerID int,
        dcAmt money,
        dcTax1 money,
        dcTax2 money,
        sChargeTag nvarchar(20)
      )
        
        DECLARE @fnPmtSumByChargeT Table 
        (
            SiteID INT,
            ChargeID int,
            dcPmtSum money
        )
    
        DECLARE @fnPmtSumByChargeT2 Table 
        (
            SiteID INT,
            ChargeID int,
            dcPmtSum money
        )
    
        DECLARE @ChargesTempT table
        (
            SiteID INT,
            ChargeID int,
            dcAmt money,
            dcTax1 money,
            dcTax2 money
        )

        Declare @ChargesT table
        (
        SiteID INT,
        ChargeID int,
        ChargeDescID int,
        sChgCategory nvarchar(50),
        sDefAcctCode nvarchar(5),
        dChgStrt datetime,
        LedgerID int,
        dcAmt money,
        dcTax1 money,
        dcTax2 money,
        sChargeTag nvarchar(20)
        )
    
        INSERT INTO @ChargesT2
        SELECT  
            C.SiteID,
            C.ChargeID, 
            C.ChargeDescID, 
            sChgCategory,
            sDefAcctCode,
            C.dChgStrt, 
            C.LedgerID,
            Coalesce(C.dcAmt,0.0) AS dcBalAmt,
            Coalesce(C.dcTax1,0.0) AS dcBalTax1, 
            Coalesce(C.dcTax2,0.0) AS dcBalTax2,
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) = 4000 THEN N'Rent'
                WHEN CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) = 4042 THEN N'LateFee'
                WHEN CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) = 4041 THEN N'AdminFee'
                WHEN CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) = 4070 THEN N'Insurance'
                WHEN CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) BETWEEN 4060 AND 4068 OR CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) BETWEEN 4071 AND 4079 THEN N'POS'
                --WHEN CAST(CA.sDefAcctCode AS INT) = 2020 THEN 'SecDep'
                ELSE N'Others'
            END as sChargeTag
        FROM Charges AS C
        INNER JOIN ChargeDesc AS CD ON C.ChargeDescID = CD.ChargeDescID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ChartOfAccts AS CA ON CD.ChartofAcctID = CA.ChartOfAcctID
        WHERE 
             C.dDeleted IS NULL
            AND C.dChgStrt <= @dend
        --2016-01-12 - Case # 237424 - C158, L005, Unit 10478, Tenant - Zach Reese.
        --Commented out dCreated evaluation. This is because A/R does not prevent backdating charges from changing historical reports. There is no way these two reports 
        --can tie out in the same period if we do not allow backdating charges that we created in a future period. Ex. Late fee created on January 2, 2016, but dChgStrt of 12/29/2015.
        --AND dCreated <= @dEnd --This is to catch a case where NSF charges were added (backdated) after the report end date, affecting historical reporting. 02102011 Josh
            AND (bNSF = 0 OR (bNSF = 1 AND dCreated <= @dend))--updated the logic to be different for NSF charges to not change reports historically; this loigc is consistant with A/R. Case # 269909
        GROUP BY C.siteID, C.ChargeID, C.ChargeDescID, sChgCategory, sDefAcctCode, C.dChgStrt, C.LedgerID, C.dcAmt, C.dcTax1, C.dcTax2, CA.sDefAcctCode

        INSERT INTO @fnPmtSumByChargeT2
        SELECT 
            SiteID, 
            ChargeID, 
            dcPmtSum 
        FROM 
            (
            SELECT
            pay.SiteID,
            Pay.ChargeID, 
            SUM(pay.dcPmtAmt) AS dcPmtSum
            FROM 
                ( 
                SELECT 
                    SiteID, 
                    ChargeID, 
                    dcPmtAmt 
                FROM Payments 
                WHERE 
                    (dDeleted Is Null)
                    --AND (bNSF = 0) --this fn must return ALL payments to calculate balances correctly
                    AND (dPmt <= @dend)
                ) AS Pay
            GROUP BY SiteID, ChargeID
            ) AS P

        INSERT INTO @fnPmtSumByChargeT2
        SELECT
            C.SiteID,
            C.ChargeID,
            0
        FROM @ChargesT2 C

        INSERT INTO @fnPmtSumByChargeT
        SELECT
            P.SiteID,
            P.ChargeID,
            SUM(P.dcPmtSum)
        FROM @fnPmtSumByChargeT2 P
        GROUP BY P.SiteID, P.ChargeID

        INSERT INTO @ChargesTempT
        SELECT
            P.SiteID,
            P.ChargeID,
            C.dcAmt - Coalesce(dbo.fnPartNonTax(C.dcAmt, C.dcTax1, C.dcTax2, P.dcPmtSum, 2),0.0),
            C.dcTax1 - Coalesce(dbo.fnPartTax1(C.dcAmt, C.dcTax1, C.dcTax2, P.dcPmtSum, 2,2),0.0), 
            C.dcTax2 - Coalesce(dbo.fnPartTax2(C.dcAmt, C.dcTax1, C.dcTax2, P.dcPmtSum,2,2),0.0)
        FROM @ChargesT2 C
        INNER JOIN @fnPmtSumByChargeT P ON C.ChargeID = P.ChargeID
        GROUP BY P.SiteId, P.ChargeID, C.dcAmt, dcTax1, dcTax2, dcPmtSum
        HAVING (dcAmt + dcTax1 + dcTax2 - dcPmtSum) > 0  -- Removed 0 sum columns: This was a major bottleneck for this function  10202009 J

        INSERT INTO @ChargesT
        SELECT 
            C.SiteID,
            C.ChargeID,
            C.ChargeDescID,
            C.sChgCategory,
            C.sDefAcctCode,
            C.dChgStrt,
            C.LedgerID,
            CT.dcAmt,
            CT.dcTax1,
            CT.dcTax2,
            C.sChargeTag
        FROM @ChargesT2 C
        INNER JOIN @ChargesTempT CT ON C.ChargeID = CT.ChargeID 

    SELECT *
    FROM @ChargesT
    AS ChargeT      
    ) AS B                              -- PROBLEM ENDS HERE

    INNER JOIN ChargeDesc AS CD ON B.ChargeDescID = CD.ChargeDescID AND B.Siteid = CD.SiteID
```

I indicated "Problem starts here" and "problem ends here" in the notes, if that helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't declare a table variable within a sub-query.

Comment: I had a feeling that was going to be it... Is there an easy work around? Maybe temp tables?

Comment: It doesn't matter what table type you use, you have to declare it before you select from it. As it stands your query doesn't make sense anyway, you're attempting to select from a table at the same time as you create it... for sure there is no data in it, so whats the point?

Comment: I didn't write it, borrowing from existing functions to save time. There's definitely data in it, like I said, it runs fine on its own.

Comment: There cannot be data in a table at the moment you declare it... You `INSERT INTO @ChargesT2` many lines after attempting to create `@ChargesT2` within a `SELECT` statement. It makes no sense at all. So little sense, that I can't actually suggest what you might be trying to accomplish...

Comment: Right... Declare it, then fill it later... what am I missing? At the end of the process, there is data in all of the table variables.

Comment: I fixed it by bumping the declarations to the beginning of the overall query (outside of the subquery). Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It's definitely an odd data set, using query language from the original developers and it is confusing/hard to follow. So I get the difficulty in following the logic. This is also a snapshot, relies on multiple layers of pre-existing logic that is not included in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a subquery the only thing you is write a select statement. You cannot write anything you want like it is a code block.

In your case, you may accomplish what you want by moving all those table variables to outside the parentheses and populating them, then inside the parentheses you just do the select. Like I said, it is not a code block, there are no local variables. There's no prettier way. SQL is a simple language for querying information. That's just how it is.

Alternatively, you may like to use Common Table Expressions ([CTE](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cte/)s) to give each subquery a name. The subqueries do not exist as any temp variable or table, just as helper names available during the main query. That may solve what you want do to.